# Static constants in global functions in C++

Tags: c++, global

Generally, are we to define and initialize static constants within a global function's header file or within its cpp file (Note I only have one global function defined per file).

Comment: Are you talking about statics local to the (global) function?

Comment: yes, I am. They are not used anywhere else, but within the global function.

Comment: If they're local to the function they can only be initialised within the definition of the function, so your question makes no sense. Perhaps you could show an example?

Answer (score 1):

If the values of the constants are known at compile time, I recommend putting them in a header file and using:

```
// No need to use static
const <type> var = <constant value>;
```

However, if you want to limit the visibility of the constant only to a source file, you can put its definition in the relevant source file only.

If the values of the constants are not known at compile time, I recommend using a function rather than exposing them through a variable.

```
extern <type> getVar();
```

Comment: They are static constants. I thought all static constants are supposed to be known at compile time?

Comment: "No need to use static":  it all depends on the visibility you want to give to your variable (outside the compilation unit or not).

Comment: @Christophe A `const` qualified variable at namespace scope has internal linkage by default, so `static` makes no difference.